# How can I politely give someone deadline on a particular task

Tags: professionalism

I am currently working with a web-host company.How do I politely give them my deadlines as they never shared their timelines even after insisting .

Comment: Put it in the contract?

Comment: Web hosting companies are a dime a dozen, just go find one that does what you want.

Comment: Not clear what the problem here is, needs more context. Are you paying the company for their services or are they just working voluntarily (for a charity, for example)? Are you an employee of your company interfacing with them, and in that case, are you the responsible person to give them deadlines, and do they know this?

Comment: Well,am a contractor employed by the company am working for to interface with this web hosting company,who at this point,I have been told that they are really frustrating staff who can only work when pushed.I am made to give them deadlines.I try reaching them for a phone talk and they seem not to be in any rush.How can I professionally let them know that I am disappointed.

Answer (score 7):

"Hi, we need that website up and running by the end of February. Can you do that?" - "Yes, no problem. " "Well, that is great. We can put that as a delivery date into our contract then".

There are different kinds of deadline - there is the time when you would like to have it, which is often called deadline. And there is a time when you absolutely need something, and getting it a day later will either involve huge cost or make the delivery to lose its value completely. Think of a New Year's firework - that has a deadline. Getting it on Jan. 2nd means it has no value.

So think what kind of deadline you have, how important it is, and how willing you are to get rid of a company that can't deliver when you want it.